# Changing the child div's font colors on parent hover

Tags: html, css

I have a question and I am not sure if it is possible, but I thought I would try asking.

Say I had three div's:

```
<div id="parent_div">

   <div id="child_div_1">Blue</div>

   <div id="child_div_2">Red</div>

</div>
```

If all text inside parent_div is set to black, how would I make the `child_div_1` and `child_div_2` change font-color to blue and red respectively, when the parent div is hovered over?

Sorry if this is a bit confusing, but is there a way to do this preferably with CSS only?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
#parent_div:hover #child_div_1 {
   color: blue;
}
#parent_div:hover #child_div_2 {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just target the relevant child elements based upon the `:hover` state of the parent:

```
/* defaults */
#parent_div div {
    color: #000; /* or whatever... */
}

/* hover rules */

#parent_div:hover #child_div_1 {
    color: blue;
}
#parent_div:hover #child_div_2 {
    color: red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/32Ewa/).

Answer (score 5):

Use the `:hover` pseudo-class on the parent element:

```
#parent_div { color: black; }

#parent_div:hover #child_div_1 { color: blue; }
#parent_div:hover #child_div_2 { color: red; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/M3WsW/